# Ext.List Touch events stop firing in Sencha Touch 2.2.1 on Samsung S3

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Running into a strange problem on the Samsung S3 with Sencha Touch 2.2.1. I have an Ext.List control and it sometimes stops scrolling. Any touch on it fires the itemtap and itemsingletap events, but the itemtouchstart, itemtouchend, and itemtouchmoves that usually fire when scrolling do nothing. Again, this happens periodically and once it happens that application (running in PhoneGap) needs to be killed and relaunched.

I haven't experienced the issue on iOS or any other Android tablet. Android release is 4.3 (standard version for S3)

Help!

Comment: Difficult to say with the information given. Can you put your phone in debugging mode and see if any (Javascript) errors are thrown in the console?

Comment: Does upgrading to 2.3.2 solve the issue? I haven't looked, however, it's always possible there was a bug. If you are using Sencha CMD, just run the command "sencha app upgrade"